# Check if payment was successful via PHP and/or JQuery?(PayPal API)

Tags: php, json, api, paypal

i am just creating a website in which i am selling something. The Website works as described:

1. The customers does choose a product
2. The customers clicks on a link to buy the product which will redirect directly to paypal.

What i want to do now is the following, after the payment was definitely successfull i want to write the paypal-email adress of the customer in database like this:

> | id | paypal  | approved |
>
> | 1  | j@d.com | yes      |

How exactly can i realize that? Do have have to redirect the customer to a "Checkout Page" afterwards and execute the PHP-Code there to read the data?

Can someone help me out here? :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Instant Payment Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).
`Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.`

So, after every transaction, PayPal will send a notification back to your server listener file which includes buyer,transaction information that you can use to store in your database.

You can download the sample php code [here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php)